# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'select'

Tags: dataframe, select, pyspark

I have an issue with pyspark dataframes. I never used it locally, and I try now. Unfortunately I run to some strange isssue. The last one is missing select attribute in DataFrame. What can I do please?

See my code (inputs in bold):

**isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame)**

```
True
```

**data.columns**

```
Index(['q', 'u', 'box',...],
  dtype='object', length=1186)
```

**data.select("box")**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [35], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 data.select("box")

File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:5575, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
   5568 if (
   5569     name not in self._internal_names_set
   5570     and name not in self._metadata
   5571     and name not in self._accessors
   5572     and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5573 ):
   5574     return self[name]
-> 5575 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'select'
```

Comment: `isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame)` means that your dataframe is a panda dataframe. Not a pyspark dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the pandas df to spark for you to select

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.select("box").show()
```